# Jetty does not launch deployed war

Tags: java, scala, jetty, sbt, war

I have a Scala application which I usually run like "sbt run". Now I packaged whole project to a .WAR file (via sbt package). Then I put the file into webapps/ directory and restarted Jetty. Logs say that the application has been deployed. And I can see it if I go to /tmp/jetty..../. But, it seems that Jetty does not run the "main" method of my application. This method runs the Twitter Storm topology, but I feel like nothing really happens once the war is deployed. This is my first time dealing with Jetty. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you understand how `war`s and application containers work? Your `main` method isn't *supposed* to be called.

Comment: @chrylis: I didn't, but now I do :) Thanks!

Comment: If you are running [Storm](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/) inside Jetty, that would be crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `main` method for webapps and wars.

If you want something to startup when the deployment is complete, you'll want to create, setup, and configure a custom [javax.servlet.ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) where your implementation of `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvente sce)` performs your twitter storm topology.

**or**

You can skip the entire deploy of a war on a standalone jetty process.  To do that you would setup an embedded jetty instance where you can do whatever you want in your own custom `main`, from starting up jetty itself, to adding your webapp, to executing your own custom code.

See the [OneWebApp embedded example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/OneWebApp.java).

In your use case, you would initialize your 'Twitter Storm topology' after the `server.start();` and before the `server.join();`

Comment: how do you run `server.start()`?